# Create a new user in crm2013 that is not based on the active directory

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

I am checking the possibility to use crm2013, I want to create all of my users out side of active directory.
Is it possible?
if you ask why, so for 3 main reasons.

1. AD is a pain in the ass when it comes to maintenance and environment duplication.
2. I need to give access to outsiders and I dont want to create them on my active directory.
3. My company does not want to use AD.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for CRM 2013 OnPremise you must use AD, there are no alternatives.

For CRM Online the synchronization between Office365 users and AD users is optional.